# $f,f',f''\geq 0$ implies $\frac{1}{f}$ convex

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f(x) \geq 0$ be monotonically increasing ($f'(x)\geq0$) and convex ($f''(x) \geq 0$), then
$$
g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}
$$
is convex. I haven't come up with a counter example yet. $f\geq 0$ is necessary, since for $f(x)=\exp(x)-10x$, $g(x)$ is only convex where $f>0$.

However the straightforward way to check by taking the derivatives
$$
g''(x) = \frac{2f'(x)^2 - f''(x)f(x)}{f(x)^3} \stackrel{!}{>} 0
$$

how can the conditions be applied? Is it wrong?

PS: As I can not delete this. Counter example: $f={1+ax+x^2}$ with $0\leq a<1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$$f''(x)f(x) - 2\left[f'(x)\right]^2 = 0 \implies f(x) = \frac{c_1}{c_2 + x}$$

Comment: Do you mean this as a counter example, since $f(x)=\frac{1}{c_2 - c_1 x}$ is positive, strictly increasing and convex for $c_1,c_2>0$ and $0<x<\frac{c_2}{c_1}$, but $g(x)=c_2 - c_1 x$ is not?

Comment: If you wanna find extremas, you have to equalize your expression of $g(x)$ with zero. The denominator of course cannot be zero, so that's the numerator. But this is a differential equation with solution as mentioned. What can we conclude ?

Comment: The only thing I can deduce, is that there is a special case for which $f\geq 0, f'\geq 0, f'' \geq 0$, but $g(x)$ is neither convex nor concave on a finite interval. Can we not exclude this special case?

Comment: This is **not** a special case.

Comment: Why? It is one family of functions, which I would call special under the infinitely many functions possible... In particular if I consider some function I know is not of this form. I mean I can demand $g''(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Diger This is a **general** solution.

Comment: A general solution for $g''(x)=0$, but I'm considering functions $f(x)$ for which $g''(x) \neq 0$. So in that case it must be either concave or convex and I'm thinking in that case it can only be convex. So after all I would need a counter example with $g''(x) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your double derivative is wrong.
$g(x) = - \frac{1}{f(x)}$ implies that $g''(x)=-\frac{2f'(x)}{f(x)^3}$
which can be seen to always be less than or equal to zero by the conditions you gave on $f$.

Comment: I guess you missed the nominator after the first derivative.

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that out.